# How to skip certain tags with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, loops, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm a beginner in Python and currently I'm trying to write a simple script using BeautifulSoup to extract some information from a web page and write it to a CSV file. What I'm trying to do here, is to go through all the lists on the web page. In the specific HTML file which I'm looking to work with, only one 'ul' has an id and I wish to skip that one and save all the other list elements in an array. My code doesn't work and I can't figure out how to solve my problem.

```
for ul in content_container.findAll('ul'):
    if 'id' in ul:
        continue
    else:
        for li in ul.findAll('li'):
            list.append(li.text)
            print(li.text)
```

here when I print the list out, I still see the elements from the ul with the id. I know it's a simple problem but I'm stuck at the moment. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `id=False`. Use this:

```
for ul in content_container.find_all('ul', id=False):
    for li in ul.find_all('li'):
        list.append(li.text)
        print(li.text)
```

This will ignore all tags that have `id` as an attribute. Also, your approach was nearly correct. You just need to check whether `id` is present in tag attributes, and not in tag itself (as you are doing). So, use `if 'id' in ul.attrs()` instead of `if 'id' in ul`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   all_uls = content_container.find_all('ul')
    #assuming that the ul with id is the first ul 
    for i in range(1, len(all_uls)):
              print(all_uls[i])
```

Comment: The OP never mentioned that *ul with id is the first ul*. So, it's better if you don't assume that.

Comment: And, if that were the case, simple slicing would do. `all_uls = content_container.find_all('ul')[1:]`